# Excel Conditional Formatting not working

Tags: excel

I'm using code to generate a number of workbooks. Each workbook contains conditional formatting. The conditional formatting works initially, but then fails when I reopen any of the workbooks.

My condition is:

```
= IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4, COLUMN())) = "H", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: Why wasn't `=A$4="H"` good enough?

Comment: Can you give us the sequence of pulldowns that you are using to create the conditional formatting?

Comment: Please be more explicit with your statement that the "conditional formatting works initially, but then fails." I don't know what the failure that you're observing looks like.

Comment: @Jeeped, it works if i change the formula to =A$4="H" as you suggest. I see that I over complicated things. Cheers.